# Add a row in data.frame by counting row numbers of another csv with names stored in the data.frame using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, mutate

I have a data frame of plant Latin names, and another folder `GBIF_data` that stores the downloaded gbif data in csv named by the Latin names in the data frame, I want to `mutate` a new column to store how much data has been downloaded from GBIF for each plant Latin name, here is the code:

```
read.csv("data.csv") %>%
  mutate(OCCURRENCES = nrow(read.delim(CSVPATH))) #csv files downloaded from GBIF use tab as delimiter so here read.delim should be used
```

The data frame looks like this (Here I show only the `CSVPATH` column which is mutated by concatenating the path before the plant Latin name and replacing the spaces in Latin name with the underscore, other columns that are not relative to the topic have been omitted):

```
   CSVPATH                                                                            
 ../GBIF_data/Lycopodium_cernuum.csv          
 ../GBIF_data/Lycopodium_japonicum.csv        
 ../GBIF_data/Lycopodiastrum_casuarinoides.csv
 ../GBIF_data/Selaginella_uncinata.csv        
 ../GBIF_data/Selaginella_doederleinii.csv    
 ../GBIF_data/Equisetum_ramosissimum.csv      
 ../GBIF_data/Ophioglossum_reticulatum.csv    
 ../GBIF_data/Osmunda_vachellii.csv           
 ../GBIF_data/Lygodium_japonicum.csv          
 ../GBIF_data/Lygodium_microphyllum.csv
```

And the name of the csv data stored in `GBIF_data` folder just replaced the space in the Latin name with the underscore `_`. When I ran the code, it reported the error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `OCCURRENCES = nrow(read.delim(CSVPATH))`.
Caused by error in `h()`:
! error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'nrow': invalid 'description' argument
```

I wonder why `dplyr::mutate` does not work in this situation? It successfully mutated the Latin names to CSVPATH by string operations but when reading and counting the row numbers of another csv file it fails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which data? the `data.frame` to be mutated or the downloaded GBIF csv data?

Comment: `read.delim` is not vectorized.  You need to loop or use `rowwise`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `rowwise` as `read.delim` is not vectorized i.e. it reads only a single file at a time

```
library(dplyr)
read.csv("data.csv") %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(OCCURRENCES = nrow(read.delim(CSVPATH))) %>%
  ungroup
```

---

Or another option is `map`

```
library(purrr)
read.csv('data.csv') %>%
   mutate(OCCURRENCES = map_int(CSVPATH, ~ read.delim(.x) %>% nrow()))
```

Comment: The `rowwise` works! Thank you! BTW `map` may not be suitable here because my data.frame has many columns, I just omitted other non-relative ones for isolating the problem.

Comment: @passiflora it would work as well, because we are just looping over the CSVPATH with map, leaving the other columns as it is

Comment: OK, I've tried and it works! Thank you for your solution!